# How to add bufler's projectiles groups to helm-mini-default-sources

Tags: helm-sources

I have this config for [bufler](https://github.com/alphapapa/bufler.el).

```
(use-package bufler
  :straight t
  :bind ("C-x C-b" . bufler)
  :config
  (setq bufler-groups
        (bufler-defgroups
          (group
           ;; Subgroup collecting these "special special" buffers
           ;; separately for convenience.
           (name-match "**Special**"
                       (rx bos "*" (or "Messages" "Warnings" "scratch" "Backtrace") "*")))
          ;; All buffers under "~/.emacs.d" (or wherever it is).
        (group
         ;; Subgroup collecting buffers in a projectile project.
         (auto-projectile))))
```

With `M-x bufler` a few groups named `Projectile: *project-name1*` `Projectile: *project-name2*` and etc. in my case.
I would like to add all this groups to `helm-mini-default-sources`, so that it looks like in `helm-mini`:

```
`Projectile: *project-name1*`
some candidates
`Projectile: *project-name2*`
some candidates
```

I suppose `helm-bufler-source` includes all the necessary Projectiles's groups and candidates. So how can I do it?

Comment: I use helm but not projectile/bufler, as far as I know, `helm-bufler-source` is one helm source and you can add it to `helm-mini-default-sources`, which is a list, you can change it any way you want (setq, push, add-to-list). You probably have other question which I don't not realize.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to add `helm-bufler-source` to `helm-mini-default-sources` with ```(setq helm-mini-default-sources '(helm-source-buffers-list helm-bufler-source) )``` for example. But it will be flat list. I would like to make each source for each projectile's group in `helm-bufler-source`

Comment: Then try to create these helm sources via `helm-build-sync-source` etc.